# What's up with these bizarre noodle cooking instructions?

Tags: translation, meaning

I recently purchased a pack of [Yángjì Shānyě brand Nanchang noodles](https://driftingcloudsnet.files.wordpress.com/2022/01/pxl_20220131_143315752.jpg?strip=info&w=1800) (阳际山野南昌拌粉). On one side of the package, under the straightforward label 食用指南, it has the following sequence of three labeled images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My meager Chinese is usually enough to puzzle out cooking instructions, but the captions here are completely incomprehensible and Google Lens can't make heads or tails of it either.  Is this poetry, a printing mistake or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an error. These Chinese characters can't be displayed correctly, they've become garbled.

I searched this product in 淘宝Taobao and got this picture. Hope this can help :)
[image]

Comment: if you need help in translating these Chinese words, please leave me a message^_^ I will try my best

Comment: Thanks for the answer and digging up the actual instructions!